# Does Eloquent cache prepared statements?

Tags: pdo, laravel-5, eloquent, prepared-statement, query-optimization

I have a series of `INSERT` statements to execute, and I would like to use Laravel's Eloquent to do so:

```
$mountain = Mountain::find(1);
$dragons = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foreach ($dragons as $id){
    $mountain->dragons()->attach($id);  // Eloquent performs an `INSERT` here
}
```

I know that Eloquent uses prepared statements, but will it *re-prepare* the same query over each iteration, or is it smart enough to cache the prepared `INSERT` statement on the first iteration, and then simply run `->execute` on each subsequent iteration?

From [PHP's PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

> By using a prepared statement the application avoids repeating the analyze/compile/optimize cycle. This means that prepared statements use fewer resources and thus run faster.

I realize that saving every prepared statement ever throughout the application lifecycle might not be the best idea, but in certain cases it seems warranted.  If Eloquent doesn't do this by default, is there a way to tell it to cache the prepared statements for a particular model operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany.php::attach`.

There is a call to `$query->insert`, which is an instance of the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class.

Now look at method `insert` in said Builder class.

I won't post the Laravel code, as it's too long, but you can clearly see that the query is compiled and executed against the current connection instantly.

The advantage of open source code is that you are free to look through it, so don't be scared of looking through it.

As noted by Your Common Sense, the time savings here are minute. If you are performing many inserts, this won't be your bottleneck. Perhaps look at queues or background services - the user shouldn't need to wait while your app performs a 1000 inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, smart application certainly **would not** keep every prepared statement open forever just in case. Such a behavior will do way much more harm than good.

And about 'good', you're putting too much meaning in that "caching" and "analyze/compile/optimizing". An idea of speed gain from prepared statement is a bit exaggerated. And speaking of your particular case, there is not much to optimize in the INSERT query, you know. You'll never be able to measure such an "optimization".

Thus, there is not much to worry about.

Comment: Thanks.  I've clarified my question, since I think this is important beyond my example use case.